# general linear group $GL_{2}(\mathbb{Z}_3).$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, group-actions

finding the order of the general linear group $GL_{2}(\mathbb{Z}_3).$ ?

Is finding the order by listing its elements only ? or is there a smarter method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try and sketch the general argument which allows the evaluation of the order of general linear groups of finite dimensional spaces. Let $K$ be an arbitrary field (not necessarily commutative) and $V$ be a left $K$-vector space of finite dimension $\mathrm{dim}_KV=n \in \mathbb{N}$. For each $k \leqslant n$ define $L_k$ to be the subset of $V^k$ consisting of all *linearly independent* sequences of vectors.

1. The linear group $\mathrm{GL}_K(V)$ has a natural (componentwise) action on each set $L_k$, all of these actions being *transitive* (this claim relies on the fact that any linearly independent subset/family can be extended to a basis). Furthermore, the action on $L_n$ is *regular* (i.e. not only is it transitive but all the elements are free, of trivial stabilisers; this is due to the fact that any morphisms that agree on a generating system are equal). Thus you can draw the conclusion that $|\mathrm{GL}_K(V)|=|L_n|$ (there are as many automorphisms as there are ordered bases).
2. For each $k<n$ there exists a natural restriction map $\rho_k \colon L_{k+1} \to L_k$, which to any sequence $x$ of linearly independent vectors indexed by the *natural* interval $[1, k+1]$ assigns its restriction to the subinterval $[1, k]$ (disregarding the "last" component). The fibre of an element $y \in L_k$ is described as:
   $$\rho_k^{-1}[\{y\}]=\left\{x \in L_{k+1}|\ (\forall i)(i \leqslant k \Rightarrow x_i=y_i) \wedge x_{k+1} \in V \setminus \left\langle\{y_i\}_{1 \leqslant i \leqslant k}\right\rangle_K\right\},$$
   where by $\langle X \rangle_K$ I am referring to the $K$-subspace of $V$ generated by the subset $X \subseteq V$. Since $y$ is a linearly independent family, the subspace its components generate is $k$-dimensional and therefore its complementary has the cardinality of the complementary of a $k$-dimensional $K$-vector space within an $n$-dimensional vector space. It is easy to see that the cardinality of such a complementary is given by $q^n-q^k$ when $K$ is a finite field of cardinality $|K|=q \in \mathbb{N}$ respectively by $|K|$ itself when $K$ is infinite.
3. We return to the decomposition of $L_{k+1}$ as a disjoint union of subsets (the fibres of $\rho_k$) all of which have an equal cardinality -- the one discussed above -- and which are in number of $|L_k|$. This establishes the recursive relation $|L_{k+1}|=\left(q^n-q^k\right)|L_k|$ in the case $K$ finite respectively $|L_{k+1}|=|K||L_k|$ in the case $K$ infinite. Since $L_0$ is a singleton (consisting of the empty family), we conclude that:
   $$|\mathrm{GL}_K(V)|=|L_n|=
   \begin{cases}
   \displaystyle\prod_{k<n}\left(q^n-q^k\right), &|K|=q \in \mathbb{N}\\
   |K|, &|K|\notin \mathbb{N} \wedge n \neq 0\\
   1, &|K|\notin \mathbb{N} \wedge n=0.
   \end{cases}$$

In your particular case, since $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}_3) \approx \mathrm{GL}_{\mathbb{Z}_3}\left(\mathbb{Z}_3^2\right)$ as groups we have $q=3$ and $n=2$ in the above notations so therefore:
$$|\mathrm{GL}_z(\mathbb{Z}_3)|=\left(3^2-1\right)\left(3^2-3\right)=48.$$

Comment: So for $GL_{3} (\mathbb{Z}_{2})$ it will be (2^3 - 1) (2^3 -2)?

Comment: Are we counting how many ways we can choose a basis?

Comment: @Smart20 You omitted a factor. $|\mathrm{GL}_3(\mathbb{Z}_2)|=\left(2^3-2^0\right)\left(2^3-2^1\right)\left(2^3-2^2\right)=168$.

Comment: @Smart20 Rather than the ambiguous expression ''how many ways we can choose'' one could say that we are rigorously counting the number of *ordered bases*.

Answer (score 3):

Just count the possible columns of a matrix in $GL_2(\Bbb{Z}_3)$. The first column has to be nonzero, which gives $9 -1 = 8$ possibilities. The second column should not be a multiple of the first column, which gives $9 - 3 = 6$ possibilities. Thus you find $8 \times 6 = 48$ elements.

Comment: from where the 9 comes?

Comment: I do not know how to count the number of columns.

Comment: they said above 81 .... I am confused

Comment: @Smart20 as the person above, note that I wrote $M_2(\mathbb{Z}_3)$ is of order $81$, not $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_3)$. You still have to figure out how many elements have determinant $0$.

Comment: So it is alll matrices (either invertible or not ) equals 81?@Bliipbluup

Comment: @Smart20 Exactly.

Comment: @Smart20 The matrices have four entries, and each entry has 3 options. Without any restrictions (like being invertible), yes, elementary combinatorics gives us that the are 81 possibilities. In this answer, however, they are looking at single columns. A column has two entries, not 4. That means there are 9 possible columns.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two approaches, both thinking of $GL_2(\Bbb Z_3)$ as the group of $2\times 2$ invertible matrices.

- Count the number of elements in $M_{2\times2}(\Bbb Z_3)$ which are rank 0 and rank 1, and conclude how many have rank 2
- Count the number of possible first columns, then count the number of possible second columns

Comment: I do not know how to do this.

Comment: @Smart20 Then I suggest you read up on basic combinatorics, choosing things with and without replacement. It really is a necessary tool in this exercise. Unless you want to list all 81 matrices and calculate their determinants.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\in\text{GL}_2(\Bbb Z_3)$. Then $\det(A)\neq 0$. So you need to solve $ad-bc\neq 0$. A fast way is to see that there are $3^4$ different matrices, so you just have to substract the solutions for $ad-bc=0$.

Comment: Ah, this is an even more clever way using eigenvalues.

Comment: Could you please show me the details of this?

Comment: @Smart20 This is more or less the same argument I provided. You just need to note that $0$ is a root of the characteristic polynomial if and only if the constant term is $0$, and that the constant term is given by the determinant (in this case $ad-bc$).

Comment: So how many solutions are there for $ad - bc =0$ ... how can I know?

Comment: where are the unknowns, where are the constant?

Comment: @Smart20 All are unknowns. a,b,c,d are the terms of a general element in $M_2(\mathbb{Z}_3)$

Answer (score 0):

We know $M_2(\mathbb{Z}_3)\cong \mathbb{Z}_3^4$ is of order 81. Since $\mathbb{Z}_3$ is a field, One idea would be to write down the characteristic polynomial of a general element and see when it has zero as a root. Elements whose characteristic polynomial has zero as a root are precisely the non-invertible matrices. The rest are precisely $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_3)$.

Writing down the elements might be faster, though.

Comment: Haaaa 81! I do not know how $M_{2}(\mathbb{Z}_3) \cong \mathbb{Z}^{4}_{3}\$

Comment: @Smart20 Viewed as vector spaces, send the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix} \mapsto (a,b,c,d)^* $ is a $\mathbb{Z}_3$--linear isomorphism, for example.